# Monetization issue in Developer portal

Tags: apigee

I am working on POC for monetization in Apigee developer portal http://dev-damuorgn.devportal.apigee.com/admin/dashboard

This is freeware working in cloud.

Here when I try to enable DevConnect Monetization and DevConnect Monetization Payment modules under DevConnect Mint category, I am getting error as “ Monetization feature not available. Please contact Apigee Support”.

Please check and revert back to us.

Comment: This feature is not available for free org

Comment: OK. Thanks for quick reply. Is there any other option to work on subscription model in APigee using Free orgn.

Comment: Take a look at defining roles in Products.  You can define a pretty robust set of rules for quotas, but reporting is much more robust in the monetization product.  See http://apigee.com/docs/developer-services/content/configuring-api-products

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this feature is not available for free orgs.  Possibly the use of API Products will do what you need in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to create a product with quota as 5 times per hour. API was designed based on "Verify API key" authentication. Using the customer ID, I was able to consume the service. But it allows more than 10 times though I set quota as 5 times per hour. What may be the issue here ?

Comment: The orgs have multiple (probably 2) message processors and unless you're using a distributed quota, you'll get 5 per MP.  One workaround would be to cut your quota to 2 or 3 (whichever is your preference) and that should do what you want.